# Explaining Providence and Prayer to Children

Tags: tefilla, children-parenting, how-to

When a young child is sick or in pain, and they say something like, "I prayed to HaShem to make it better but he didn't do anything" what's a good way to answer that kind of question?

Answer (score 4):

How you phrase things will depend on the age of the child, but here are some points you can cover.  I'm not a parent, but I've seen parents and teachers offer all of these and remember being told some of them when I was a child.

- Just because you didn't see something happen doesn't mean Hashem didn't do anything.  Most of what Hashem does we don't see directly.  (Depending on the situation: maybe you're healing faster than you would have because of your prayers.)
- When praying it's best if you say how you feel but don't ask for specific outcomes.  Hashem isn't a giant order-fulfillment service.
- "He didn't do anything... *yet*."  Be patient.  (This doesn't apply to all situations.)
- Hashem hears all prayers.  Sometimes the answer is "no".  It's hard to understand why, but he has his reasons.  (I would use this one only for an older child; I don't think a 5-year-old is likely to understand this, but a 10-year-old could.)